# Regular Expression capture

Tags: c#, regex

Using C# the following regex captures the data I need from the sample text data. However this is using groups. 
I only need the value of the property (i.e. 0x05AC), how would the regex look like if I wanted to access the property through match.Value ?, In other words I only want to capture the property value for Model from the data string.
If someone can explain the solution it will be great.

Thanks

```
string data = @"
ID                  : 40
Name                : 2015
Model               : 0x05AC
Product             : Generic
Number              : 0x12A8";
var match = Regex.Match(data, @"Model[ ]*:[ ]*(0x.+\S)");
var result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Why would that be a good thing? You have something readable that works - changing it can easily make it unreadable. That is - what's the value in what you are asking for?

Comment: Why use regex on such a simple task that can be easily achieved using string operations?

Comment: I have a huge file containing many entries like the one above, and each set of properties like the one above can be different than the other (different order and different set of properties). Nothing in the file is standard other than the separator between each set of properties. Parsing it would be complete hell and I cannot change the file either.

Comment: Does that also mean that there is always `Model` followed by 15 spaces, a colon, another space and then `0x....`? You could perhaps use a positive lookbehind.

Comment: Yes it does, but the model prop is not always present.

Comment: Huh? But how would you then identify the model value and not confuse it with the Number value (0x12A8 in your sample).

Comment: Well I need to check if the property name exists

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg =new Regex(@"Model[^:]*:\s*(?<model>0x[A-F0-9]+)");
var match=reg.Match(data);
var result=match.Groups["model"].Value;
```

Comment: You might want to use `if (match.Success) {...}`.

Comment: I guess this is better than using indexes but it's still using groups…